# In iOS Swift How can I convert the time from the format "Tue Aug 27 2019 07:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

From backend i am getting date as "Tue Aug 27 2019 07:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".
In iOS Swift, How can I convert the time from the format "Tue Aug 27 2019 07:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" to YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Do you have a string with the text "Tue Aug 27 2019 07:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" or do you have a Date, which appears like that in the debugger?

Comment: Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+convert+date)?

Comment: I am receiving the date string from backend like this {"date" : "Tue Aug 27 2019 07:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" }

Answer (score 0):

Removed 'GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' from date string what are you getting from server
then use this -

```
 let date = self.convertDateStringToFormatString1(dateString: 
 "Tue Aug 27 2019 07:01:59", fromFormat: "E MMM dd  yyyy hh:mm:ss" , toFormat: 
 "YYYY-MM-dd")

 func convertDateStringToFormatString1(dateString:String, fromFormat : String, 
 toFormat : String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = fromFormat
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = toFormat
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    }
```